# R5613L understandig what MOSFET to use

Tags: mosfet, battery-charging, protection, nmos, pmos

I want to add a battery-protection to my circuit including a switch to disconnect the battery from the rest. I found the R5613L from Nisshinbo ([Manufacturer product site with datasheet](https://www.nisshinbo-microdevices.co.jp/en/products/lithium-ion-battery-protection/spec/?product=r5613)).

On page 26, they show the "typical application circuit" including a MOSFET.
[image]

Because it seems that nobody is using the same symbols I learned to not trust the pictures in the datasheet. I am not sure what MOSFET to use here. on Page 11, they write about NMOS and PMOS. Is this the same as enhancement FET? Or could it also be depletion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, Japanese datasheets! Without looking at the test circuits marked on the last column for the respective specs it's almost impossible to "guess" what they really mean!

**NOTE:** One thing I noticed is that V<sub>OH2</sub> is for DOUT pin PMOS on, not COUT. Because the test circuit is given for DOUT pin.

---

Anyway.

Apparently DOUT and COUT pins have CMOS totem pole drivers:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftdAgU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Unlike BJT totem pole driver which works as a buffer, CMOS totem pole works as an inverter. So, when the input (DRV) is low the PMOS turns on and the output becomes HIGH. Likewise, when the input (DRV) is high the NMOS turns on and the output becomes LOW.

So, for COUT and DOUT pins, instead of using "Output HIGH" and "Output LOW", they preferred to use "Output PMOS ON" and "Output NMOS ON" for some reason I have no idea about. So with PMOS and NMOS they refer to the internal CMOS totem pole driver's switches. Strange, innit?

So, **you are expected to use NMOS as external switches**. Don't worry about the terms they used. The data on p.11 and p.14 are actually as follows:

- V<sub>OL1</sub>: COUT pin output LOW level
- V<sub>OH1</sub>: COUT pin output HIGH level
- V<sub>OL2</sub>: DOUT pin output LOW level
- V<sub>OH2</sub>: DOUT pin output HIGH level

<sup><sub>None of the battery protection and charge-discharge monitoring ICs I came across suggests using PMOS **at low side**.</sub></sup>

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!